# Desktop Environments keeps reverting to US keyboard layout. How do I stop this?

Tags: keyboard-layout, mate-desktop

I am using Fedora 25 with the MATE desktop. I start MATE with the "startx" command.

Every time I start MATE, it sets my keyboard to a US layout. I have to change it back by clicking System -> Administration -> Keyboard. Changing it from the control centre doesn't work.

Is there a way to tell MATE to permanently keep the keyboard layout I select?

In a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279850/how-can-i-stop-my-debian-cinnamon-desktop-from-always-starting-with-the-us-engli), it's implied I should have a keyboard configuration file in /etc/default/keyboard, but I have none.